# Can you use excel formulas on report data?

Tags: excel, oracle, excel-formula, report

So i have some rdfs that download from the server through rwservlet as excels (xls). My question is: can i use excel formulas like sum on the report returned data?

I tried formatting the data (i think here relies the problem as it seem it doesn't affect the data that's already there) and modifying the decimal separator to "." from the rdf. Neither work, not separate or together; the sum formula returns 0. However if i overwrite new data over report data in a field, sum works.
It seems to me it sees all the data returned from the report like text and the formatting doesn't affect the already there data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go to the root of the problem: the format mask in the rdf was adding a space for sign for the positive numbers. Hence excel was not recognizing it as a number. Problem is after i put a "-" in the format mask to get rid of the space excel re-formats the number automatically from 1.00 to 1 for example. So basically the format mask in the rdf is overwritten, i could not use it at all and i'd get the same result.